# Prevent clubbing of server side error messages on top

Tags: 8, theming, forms

I have inline form errors module enabled on my drupal 8 site. The server-side errors that appear on form submission are appearing as clubbed together like below:
[image]

How to change this error language and prevent clubbing for example if there would have been multiple errors the message would have been "2 errors have been found: FieldName1, FieldName2".

Is it a part of core and how to show errors in different lines?

Comment: You have the Inline Form Errors module enabled, OK. And what happens when you disable it?

Comment: They do appear in different lines. However I am using IFE and need it enabled. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable that module to return to the more traditional line-by-line error output globally, or hook into it programatically form-by-form:

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'foo_form') {
    $form['#disable_inline_form_errors'] = TRUE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah but I need inline form errors as well. I am validating data at client side as well but some data needs to be validated at server side end.

Comment: The module doesn't provide a way to have the inline error messages but also keep the error messages at the top if that's what you're looking for. For that you'd either have to register your own class for the `form_error_handler` service which handles the different logic, or turn off IFE and re-implement the input-specific error message logic.